# I have date column like this "20210527181345" how to convert this string to timestamp SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query-builder

I have date column like this "20210527181345" pls help to convert this string to timestamp in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select date_parse('20210527181345','%Y%m%d%H%s%i');
```

Answer (score 2):

In Mysql, you can use `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20210527181345','%Y%m%d%H%s%i');
```